# How can I generate a distribution whose values are distributed according to an input array?

Tags: matlab, probability

I have written the following script which should create an array which contains the probability mass of every number from 1 to N, defined following the robust soliton distribution. The values of delta, N and M are completely arbitrary.

```
N = 300; % length of the the array
in = [1:1:N]; % index array

delta = 0.5; 
M = 70;
R = N/M;

t(1:M-1) = 1./(in(1:M-1)*M);
t(M) = log(R/delta)/M;
t(M+1:N) = 0;
```

What I'm trying to do now is using the arrays in and t in order to "generate" in some way a pdf which returns the numbers in the array **in** with the probability contained in the array **t**. I have already looked in the manual and I found the makedist function, but I didn't find an option which allowed me to use as arguments two input arrays. I don't really know where to look.

The numbers generated should be used to encode packets using LT codes (for didactic purposes, I'm just trying to understand how to build them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you would like to be able to randomly pick numbers i element of 1:N with probabilities proportional to the value t(i).

First, let's restructure the unnormalized probabilities into an array that lists the ranges of each value; I.e. 
t-> p {0,0.01,0.05,0.09, etc} I just used random values here.

Then what we can do is randomly pick a number from 0 to 1, and find the value of i associated with that random number. I.e. if we get 0.07, then the value of i would be 3 in my example because 0.07 is between 0.05 and 0.09 and the value i=3 has a 4% probability of being picked;

```
s = sum(t);
p = double.empty(N,1);

for i = 1:N
    if(i == 0)
    p(i) = 0
    else
    p(i) = p(i-1) + t(i-1)/s;
    end
end
```

Now whenever we need a number from the distribution, we can use matlab's inherent find function

```
r = rand()
i = max(find(r-p>0)) % this could probably be optimized
```

What this does by example: If we use the same r and p as above:

```
 r-p = {0.07, 0.06, 0.02, -0.02, etc} 
 find(r-p>0) = {1,2,3}
```

Comment: Remove the `{}` braces as well as the `()` in front of the `for` loop. That's invalid MATLAB syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works for now but I had to change the min function to the max function because otherwise the result is always 1.